# Analytic form of power series model?

Tags: power-series, recursion

**The Setup**

I am dealing with the recursive equation
$$w_t = \alpha + (1-\alpha)w_{t-1}, $$
with $0 < \alpha < 1$ and some starting point $w_0$. I am trying to prove an expression for $w_t$ that does not rely on $w_{t-1}$.

So for instance,
$$w_1 = \alpha + (1-\alpha)w_0,$$
and \begin{align*}
w_2 &= \alpha + (1-\alpha)[\alpha + (1-\alpha)w_0] \\
&= \alpha(1 + (1-\alpha)) + (1-\alpha)^2w_0.
\end{align*}
At this point I know that
$$\alpha(1 + (1-\alpha)) + (1-\alpha)^2 = 1$$
so I can rewrite $w_2$ as
$$w_2 = 1-(1-\alpha)^2 + (1-\alpha)^2w_0.$$

**The Problem**

I am trying to generalize the result to $w_t$, but am having trouble proving that
$$\alpha(1 + (1-\alpha)^1 + \ldots + (1-\alpha)^{t-1}) + (1-\alpha)^t = 1$$
for any positive integer $t$.

Any strategies on how to prove this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if simple, I shall go through the steps. We have $$w_t = \alpha + (1-\alpha)w_{t-1}$$ and what is not pleasant is the constant term. So, let $w_t=u_t+k$ and replace
$$u_t+k=\alpha + (1-\alpha)u_{t-1}+(1-\alpha)k$$ To get rid of the constant, write
$$k=\alpha+(1-\alpha)k\implies k=1$$ and then
$$u_t=(1-\alpha)u_{t-1}\implies u_t=C (1-\alpha)^{t-1}\implies w_t=1+C (1-\alpha)^{t-1}$$ But, for $t=0$, you have
$$w_0=1+C \implies C=w_0-1$$

Answer (score 0):

First try to solve $a_t = (1 - \alpha) a_{t - 1}$ with the guess $a_t = Cr^t$. Then try $w_t = D + a_t$ and solve for $D$. This is the usual approach to solving linear recurrence relations. Let me know if you need more guidance.

Answer (score 0):

If the sequence converges, it converges to the solution of

$$w_\infty=\alpha+(1-\alpha)w_\infty$$ which is $$w_\infty=1.$$

Then by subtraction, the recurrence can be rewritten as

$$w_t-w_\infty=(1-\alpha)(w_{t-1}-w_\infty)$$

which, by induction has the obvious solution

$$w_t-w_\infty=(1-\alpha)^t(w_0-w_\infty)$$

or

$$w_t=(1-\alpha)^t(w_0-w_\infty)+w_\infty=(1-\alpha)^t(w_0-1)+1.$$

---

**Technical note:** the sequence does not need to converge for the computation to be valid, it works for any $\alpha$. (If it does not converge, $w_\infty$ is an unstable equilibrium point.)